# How to toggle sidebar (hide/show) by click and by minimize?

Tags: jquery, html, sidebar

I have a sidebar on my index.html and on the right side I want to have my content. At the end of body you wil see the jquery code where I toggle sidebar's active class and change the button text between hide and show. This works well. Then I have added media queries that when User minimize page sidebar is going to be dissapear again but in this case the button's text has to be change as well, this part is not working well, Do you have any idea how i can achieve it?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>Sidebar Navigation</title>
</head>

<body>

    <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar  -->
            <nav id="sidebar">

                <div class="sidebar-header text-center">
                    <h3 class="display-4">Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="container p-3">



                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Page Content  -->
            <div id="content" class="w-100 px-5 py-2">
                <div class="row p-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Hide Showbar</button>

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Popper.JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                     $(this).text($(this).text() == "Show Sidebar" ? "Hide Sidebar" : "Show Sidebar");

                });
                if ($('#sidebar').css('margin-left') == '-320px') {
                    console.log('IT is');

                     $(this).text($(this).text() == "Show Sidebar" ? "Hide Sidebar" : "Show Sidebar");

                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
      -ms-flex-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #173f5f;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #12314a;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -320px;
}

.btn {
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}



.card-body {
  color: #363636;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -320px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }

  .container {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }

}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

and here jsfiddle demo
https://jsfiddle.net/c17g9ax5/

Answer (score 0):

just edit you css  remove span `#sidebarCollapse {
    display: none;
  }`

[Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/L60r7hf2/2/)

Comment: Yes but button text wont change on resize

Comment: i didn't get you,you said when size is less then button should be hidden correct?